# Must I release the OpenAL context here?

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, memory-management, openal

When setting up OpenAL, the Leaks Instruments tells me that I am leaking alContext here:

```
alDevice = alcOpenDevice(NULL);
if (!alDevice) {
    return NO;
}

alContext = alcCreateContext(alDevice, 0); // leaking!
if (!alContext) {
    return NO;
}

BOOL success = alcMakeContextCurrent(alContext);
if (!success) {
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

Where and how should I release the alContext?

Comment: Is `alContext` a variable local to that function, or does it still exist after the return call?

Comment: It still exists afterwards. Instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would cleanup:

```
alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
alcDestroyContext(alContext);
alcCloseDevice(alDevice);
```

And you would just call these methods whenever you are done with the context... that depends on your application and how you are using it, but probably in a `dealloc` somewhere.

Comment: The context isn't needed anymore as soon as my app quits. But until then, I need it. Thanks.